# Cannot get the_content() to change font color on custom WP theme

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I've run into a small problem coding my own WP theme from scratch (with a static Home page and a separate Blog page). I can't change the font-color of my blog posts (that display after I click them). So I have a two-part question:

1. Why can't I get the_content to change color on my single.php page? Here's my code:

   ```
   <?php
       get_header();
       the_post(); 
       if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
           the_post_thumbnail('large');
       }
   ?>  
   <div class="white">
      <div class="container">
           <h2 class="black-text light" style="margin:0;">
               <?php the_title();?>
           </h2>
           <h5 class="black-text" style="margin:0 0 7% 0;">
               <?php the_author();?>
           </h5>
           <p class="black-text">
               <?php the_content();?>    
           </p> 
       </div>
   </div>

   <?php
       get_footer();
   ?>
   ```

What's happening is on my single.php page (which I'm using to design my individual blog posts), I've put 'the_title();' in an `<h2>`, 'the_author();' in an `<h5>`, and 'the_content();' in a `<p>`. I've also told each of those elements to show as black text. However, only the `<h2>` and `<h5>` change to black text. When I inspect it with Dev Tools, what's happening is WP is ignoring my hard-coded `<p>`, and creating new `<p>` of its own WITHOUT the black-font formatting.

My second question:

2. Am I even doing this right?? It displays fine on my local development, but am I doing this all in the correct way? Basically, I have a front-page.php that displays my Home Page. Then I have an index.php that shows the main blog page with small excerpts. Then, when a user clicks on a single blog post to open it, the individual post is shown with the single.php template. Is this right?

If a reference would help, you can see it here: www.uptowndownentertainment.com/blog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is missing from your post, you need to indent it with four spaces to make it show up. Looking at [this page](http://www.uptowndownentertainment.com/test-page/) you seem to have added this before the content:

```
<p class="black-text" style="color:black !important;">
```

But the actual text is inside another paragraph element so it's not affected by that code. Wordpress automatically does this when writing posts. The easiest solution might be to add this to your style.css:

```
.container p {
 color: black;
}
```

And then remove the style markup from the headers and paragraphs. It's always better to keep styles in the CSS instead of right in the code.

Comment: Just to clarify: by default WP will automatically wrap the content in `<p>` tags, as the *content can contain more than one paragraph.* WP isn't actually  ignoring the `<p>` tag you inserted into your template; it's still including them in the DOM. Since you can't have a `<p>` inside another `<p>` the *browser* is treating it as invalid, and closing your tag immediately.
@yayheartbeat is correct: the easiest method to fix this is to edit `style.css` rather than attempting to do this inline.